# Bootstrap 5 with Vue and shadow dom

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, shadow-dom

I am trying to use bootstrap 5 with Vuejs and shadow dom (Vue custom element). The standard bootstrap css classes work, but the bootstrap components do not seem to work.
I have tried the solution suggested in https://ilikekillnerds.com/2022/08/how-to-use-bootstrap-javascript-components-inside-of-shadow-dom-web-components/ which initializes the bootstrap 5 component properly but all the event handlers are not bound.

I have tried implementing the dropdown component by initializing the Dropdown component from bootstrap myself.

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" ref="dropdown">
    <button
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      id="dropdownMenuButton1"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
    >
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap'
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const dropdown = ref()

  let dropdownEl: Dropdown

  onMounted(() => {
    if (dropdown.value) {
      dropdownEl = new Dropdown(dropdown.value)
    }
  })
```

The dropdown does not work(I'm assuming due to the shadow dom, this works on non-shadow dom vuejs project). Do all events like closing/opening the dropdown have to be manually implemented?

Comment: Hi Prasen. Did you find out what was causing it?

Comment: @WooDzu Yeah, so, Bootstrap binds events in the dom but does not have access to the shadow dom. I had to manually bind the events to the Bootstrap element to make it work.